# small icon not showing of last push notification in KitKat android?

Tags: android, push-notification

I have to show small and large push notification icon on push notification banner.
but small icon not showing on last received push notification and also blink small icon when I hard touch and scroll see screenshot attachment. Shown red arrow

I am facing this issue in Kitkit version. can any one suggest me solution

[image]

Comment: Does the problem occur in other phones or emulators?